# Search finds too many users

Tags: user-profile-service, people-search

I have a problem with the SharePoint search crawler for user profiles - it finds/indexes too many user profiles, and I don't understand why. The user profile service application synchronizes around 1500 profiles from the AD (an AD group with a filter to target a specific set of users), yet the search service application crawls/finds around 7000 items. When performing a search the results contain people not included in the User Profile Service Application import.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this problem, here's the solution I found. I had multiple web applications and multiple User Profile Service Applications and Search Service Applications, but the service application associations were wrong. Once I had corrected them the search crawler indexed the correct user profiles.